# Running PyQGIS Scripts in Las Palmas from Models created in Dufour?

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7

I am programming with `PyQQIS` using `QGIS DuFour`(old version) and `QGIS Las Palmas`(latest version) and Python 2.7 on my system.

On `QGIS DuFour` I can export my model to Python script, on `QGIS Las Palmas` I can't.

I have synchronize my Python system with `PyQgis` and `QGIS Las Palmas` so I can create Python QGIS script standalone OK with that.

Now I want to export all my model from `QGIS DuFour` to Python scripts and run these scripts with  `PyQgis` from `QGIS Las Palmas`.

How can I do that?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question per question.

Comment: i update my ask

Answer (score 1):

The latest **Processing plugin** version has brought back the function to export models to scripts. This plugin has become a core plugin for QGIS lately and resides within the QGIS directory. The older versions of QGIS such Dufour uses the plugin externally and it resides in the `.qgis2/python/plugins/` directory.

My guess is there is a conflict between the two plugin versions. I would probably suggest either deleting (or moving) the processing folder inside your `.qgis2/python/plugins/` directory then load QGIS Las palmas.

You should also note that there have been significant changes made to the processing plugin, especially a number of algorithms in the toolbox (e.g. the parameters of various algorithms have been modified). So it may be likely that when you try to run a script originally from QGIS Dufour, you may experience errors.

Comment: you say latest Processing plugin version has brought back the function to export models to python scripts ?

Comment: @Mar - I am using QGIS 2.18.0 and the **Processing** version which came with it is 2.12.99. The option to export a model to a python script is available as you can [see here](http://imgur.com/a/jALrB).

Comment: yes i see now is available thnx all problem solve

Comment: @Mar - Most welcome, glad it helped and good luck =)